# What is the limit of $\dfrac{\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt{h}}{\lim_{x\to\infty} 1/x}$

Tags: analysis, limits

I'd like to know the result of the following quotient:

$\dfrac{\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt{h}}{\lim_{x\to\infty} 1/x}$.

I think the result is $0$ because the first derivative of $\sqrt{h}$ is $\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{h}}$ and $- \dfrac{1}{2 x^2}$ for $1/x$. Thus, $\sqrt{h}$ approaches 0 faster and faster the closer $h$ gets to $0$. Whereas $1/x$ approaches 0 slower and slower the more $x$ grows to infinity.

In case my reasoning is true, I still think it is not formal enough. How could this be done more formally?

Comment: You cannot treat the limits together when you have different variables.  This is because you don't know whether or not $x\to\infty$ at the same rate that $h\to 0$.  What you can say is that the limit in the numerator is $0$ and the limit in the denominator is $0$.  More than that you cannot say.

Comment: You should rephrase the question as to what this fraction equals.

Comment: You have a (candidate) quotient of two numbers which happen to be both $0$, the quotient is quite simply undefined.

Comment: You say you want to find the limit of the following quotient, but your quotient already is a quotient of limits. You're using tools to analyze a function of the form $\lim_{x \to c} \frac p q$ or $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac p q$ for $p, q$ two functions, but your limitand is not of that form.

Comment: Of course, you all are right. Actually, I wanted to know which one approaches zero fastest and thought this would be a way to ask this. But that was obviously wrong!

Comment: @stats_guy Then you should defined what does it mean for a function to approach something faster than another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\lim_{h \to 0} \sqrt h = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x = 0$.  Therefore, your quotient is simply $\frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined.

In general, the equality
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a}g(x)}
$$
will only hold if both $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ are finite, and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) \neq 0$.

---

It looks like you're trying to evaluate something like
$$
\lim_{h \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt h}{1/f(h)}
$$
where $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = \infty$.  Note that the limit depends on which $f$ you happen to choose.  That is, it matters how fast $x$ approaches infinity relative to how fast $h$ approaches zero, and we get no information about this from the problem as you've presented it.

---

On the other hand, a limit like
$$
\lim_{(h,x) \to (0,\infty)} \frac{\sqrt h}{1/x} = \lim_{(x,h)} x\sqrt h
$$
would fail to exist.

Answer (score 3):

This quotient simply does not make sense because the denominator is $0$. If you are trying to apply l'Hopital's rule or something like that, this rule applies to the limit of a quotient (in some circumstances); not to the quotient of two limits.

Comment: The quotient of the limits is even okay in some cases, since you can sometimes pull the limit out (when the denominator doesn't go to 0), but the variables aren't even the same

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out already, the problem does not make sense as stated, since you are dividing by zero.

We can make a few changes that might be towards what you are looking for. Note that $\lim_{x\to \infty} 1/x$ is the same as $\lim_{x\to 0} x$. Replacing $1/x$ with $x$ and moving the limit outside we find:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \infty$$